# Groebner base from tdeg order to plex order

Tags: maple, groebner-basis

I try to solve an equation by using Groebner bases. When I use Maple to find its Groebner basis with [*plex order*](/https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=Groebner%2FMonomialOrders), Maple take too long to calculate and the proceed does not terminate. Thus, I try to find with [*tdeg order*](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=Groebner%2FMonomialOrders) and the proceed takes seconds.

Now, I have the Groebner basis with *tdeg order*. I want to use it to find the Groebner basis with *plex order*. Can I do it in Maple?

Comment: I don't think that it will be easier to calculate a Groebner basis with plex order from the groebner basis with tdeg order than from the original polynomials, but I don't know much about groebner base. Why do you want a groebner basis with plex order?

Comment: I face to a problem which requires full information of solutions of a system of polynomials. To my knowledge, it need to find their Groebner basis with plex order. I simply think of a code (in Maple) to calculate it from the one with tdeg order.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Two options are using Walk and FGLM commands, both from Groebner package. You can read about these two commands and see some examples of using them to convert a Grobner basis from a monomial order to a Grobner basis in another monomial order in the documentation of these commands in Maple's help manual.

- https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Groebner/Walk
- https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Groebner%2fFGLM